# Show that $\{x\}\in \mathbb{B}(X)$ for every $x\in X$

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, borel-sets, measurable-sets

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a Hausdorff space, and let $\mathbb{B}(X)$ be the Borel $\sigma$ algebra on $X$. The question is,

> Is it true that, if $x\in X$, then $\{x\}\in \mathbb{B}(X)$?

The reason why I ask is because of the previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3798749) I made; the answer shows that one can determine a Radon measure at $\{x\}$, but I need to verify that $\{x\}\in \mathbb{B}(X)$.

Comment: Since $X$ is Hausdorff, $\{x\}$ is closed and trivially Borel, ain't it?

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä ".. and trivially Borel" Why? Isn't $\mathbb{B}(X)$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the collection of open subsets of $X$?

Comment: A $\sigma$-algebra is closed wrt. taking the complement and any closed set is the complement of some open set. Hence $B(X)$ has to contain all open and closed subsets of $X$.

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä Put $A:=\{x\}$. Then $X\setminus A$ is open and belongs to $\mathbb{B}(X)$. Since $\mathbb{B}(X)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we have $A=(X\setminus A)^c\in \mathbb{B}(X)$. Is this correctly understood?

Comment: Yeah! Btw, notice that if $X$ is NOT Hausdorff, $A$ may not be closed and the argument fails.

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä That's easier than I thought, lol. If you can write your comments into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Yeah might be more legible in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X$ is Hausdorff $\{x\}$ (a singleton) is closed and $U = X \setminus \{x\}$ is open. Since $B(X)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, it's closed under taking the complement:
$$
B(X) \ni X \setminus U = X \setminus ( X \setminus \left\{ x\right\} ) = \left\{ x \right\}
$$